# Converted jar to exe file but not working after installation

Tags: java, mysql, advanced-installer, java-deployment-toolkit

I converted my first java swing app to exe using advanced installer and inno setup(Tried both no result).
Considering Inno Setup : on double clicking nothing happens

Considering : Advanced Installer -> On executing my app open but after providing credentials nothing happens so i assume it may be database issue.

About my app: It is a small swing based saving and retrieving data of employees payment.
Database used : MySQL

I had imported database schema to client PC and made .exe file of app so that after installing it can access data.
The Jar files runs successfully and able to access the data as well.

So i think while creating .exe is their anything to be done about database .

Please suggest me where i am mistaken .

Answer (score 0):

Download Launcher4J Software and build Exe out of jar file!
This is the Best and all fixes will done!

Comment: @haninullah786  hi, I made exe using launch4j but problem remains same it opens and nothing happens

Comment: Did you set the Main Class in Launch4J

Comment: yes main class is set properly and library is also set .... Is anything related to database has to be done while creating exe (MySQL connector is present in lib folder)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more like an application issue rather than an installer generated one. Have you tried to debug your application code after it is deployed using a setup package?

Also, in Advanced Installer, under Java Products view of your project there is a Virtual Machine section where you can choose to save the output and error stream in a log file. The log file will be created at app runtime just beside the EXE launcher. Maybe this will help you to catch some errors logged.